# Не получается запустить Job в Quartz.net

Tags: c#, .net-core, quartz

Цель запустить job в Quartz в приложении .net core 3.1 c dependency injection. Беру самый простой пример с официального [сайта](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html) . В итоге ставлю бп внутри joba результат нулевой. Не пойму что упустил.

> startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddQuartz(q =>
        {
            q.ScheduleJob<ExampleJob>(trigger => trigger
                .WithIdentity("Combined Configuration Trigger")
                .StartAt(DateBuilder.EvenSecondDate(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(7)))
                .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(x => x.WithInterval(10, IntervalUnit.Second))
                .WithDescription("my awesome trigger configured for a job with single call")
            );
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

> exampleJob.cs

```
    public class ExampleJob : IJob
{
    private readonly IApplicationBuilder _app;
    public ExampleJob(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        _app = app;
    }
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        _app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Program.cs стандартный, ничего в нем не менял

Answer (score 5):

Ответ найден. Оказывается нужно было добавить QuartzHostedService. А также обязательно зарегистрировать свой job в DI контейнере.

```
   public static class Services
{
    public static void ConfigureApplicationServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        //services.Configure<QuartzOptions>(configuration.GetSection("Quartz"));
        services.AddQuartz(q =>
        {
            q.ScheduleJob<ExampleJob>(trigger => trigger
                .WithIdentity("Combined Configuration Trigger")
                .StartAt(DateBuilder.EvenSecondDate(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(7)))
                .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(x => x.WithInterval(10, IntervalUnit.Second))
                .WithDescription("my awesome trigger configured for a job with single call")
            );
        });
        services.AddQuartzHostedService(options =>
        {
            // when shutting down we want jobs to complete gracefully
            options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
        });
        services.AddTransient<ExampleJob>();
    }
}
```